# Color scheme is being remembered for each file in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, color-scheme

I don't know if this is normal, but when I change the color scheme from the user preferences it only takes effect on new files that I open. Files that are already open show up with the previous color scheme.

Is there any way to change this behavior and apply the new color scheme to all files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I face this issue too. Just close the tab and reopen it, and the file should load with the proper color scheme.